# What advantage do we get if we specify Frombody and FromUri attribute in web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

What are the benefits/advantages we get if we specify this frombody and fromuri attribute in web-api?

Answer (score 1):

Web API parameter binding expects simple type values coming from query string, and complex types like array coming from the body of the request. Hence if you have an action method like this one:

```
 public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id, string[] names)
        {
            return Ok("Method Called");
        }
   }
```

,and if you want to formulate your request like this:

**/api/employees?id=1&names=Fred&names=Anna**

, then without [FromUri] the value of "names" parameter won't be bound.

So your API method must be like this in order to get all parameters bound:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id,[FromUri] string[] names)
{
   return Ok("Method Called");
}
```

More from here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api